# How can I return a array of string[5] from a function that returns a string[]?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm wondering why if my function is meant to return a string of indeterminate length, I can't return a string array of definite length.

This function, for example doesn't compile

```
function BindingTypeList() public pure returns(string[]  memory) {
        return ["DocumentTemplate", "Definition", "RepAndWarranty", "Restriction", "Entitlement"];
    }
```

the error message is `TypeError: Return argument type string memory[5] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory[] memory.`

It seems like they are saying that `string[5]` is incompatible with `returns(string[])`. I don't get that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others have this problem the way it can be done is:

```
function BindingTypeList() public pure returns(string[]  memory) {
   string[] memory names = new string[5];
   names[0] = "DocumentTemplate";
   names[1] = "Definition";
   ...
   names[4] = "Entitlement";
   return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;` in your contract to enable returning the array of strings.

Comment: Actually not, at least not in >8.0.0. I think it is no longer experimental.